# Need help with proving that group is not finitely-generated

Tags: group-theory, rational-numbers

I need to prove that $(\mathbb{Q}^*, \times)$ (i.e rationals, zero excluded, under multiplication) is not finitely generated.

So, suppose that G is finitely-generated.
That means there exist a finite set $S=\left\{x_1, x_2,...,x_n\right\}\subset \mathbb{Q}^*$ s.t. $\langle S\rangle=\mathbb{Q}^*$.

Now, all I need to do is to find a number $y\in\mathbb{Q}^*$ that cannot be generated by $S$.

Naively, I first thought of prime numbers, but that surely won't work.
Please help me out here... how can I find a number $y\in\mathbb{Q}^*$ that cannot possibly be multiplication of $x_i$-s from $S$?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: suppose you have finitely many generators... there would be finitely many denominators... so, there would be finitely many prime factors... But....?? Infinitely many primes exists... So?

Comment: Can you see why, for arbitrary $p_i, q_i$, $\;\dfrac{1}{1+q_1 \cdot q_2\cdots q_n}$ is not in the subgroup generated by $\left\{\frac{p_1}{q_1},\frac{p_2}{q_2},\ldots,\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right\}\;?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea about prime numbers is a good one!  Let $T$ be the set of primes which appear in either the numerator or denominator of some element of $S$.  Then $T$ is finite (why?) so there is some prime $p \not \in T$.  Show by unique factorization that $p$ cannot be the product of powers of elements of $S$.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.